# Gdal.warp broken in version 2.3.3?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have two versions of Python gdal running in different environments. One is slightly older (2.1.1) and gdal.Warp seems to work just fine there, the newer version doesn't. Has anyone else had this problem?

Edit: 
I'm calling gdal.Warp like this:

```
gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_raster, dstSRS='EPSG:3083')
```

Error traceback, in the env with the newer version, looks like this:

```
runfile('C:/Users/mrt2594/clip&reproj_GRACE_TX.py', wdir='C:/Users/mrt2594')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-b1b650156b3c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/mrt2594/clip&reproj_GRACE_TX.py', wdir='C:/Users/mrt2594')

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\osgeo-lab\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\osgeo-lab\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/mrt2594/clip&reproj_GRACE_TX.py", line 33, in <module>
    gdal.Warp(out_savepath, src_tif, options = clip_specs)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\osgeo-lab\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 579, in Warp
    return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\osgeo-lab\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 3189, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName
    return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)

TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestName', argument 4 of type 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'
```

Answer (score 2):

`GDALWarpAppOptions` has been added with GDAL 2.1 and I suspect the issue is related to signature change/default values in function arguments due to message

> TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestName', argument 4 of type 'GDALWarpAppOptions *'

You may try the following (untested as I do not have the exact versions installed)

```py
if hasattr(gdal, 'GDALWarpAppOptions'):
    warpOptions = gdal.GDALWarpAppOptions([])
    gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_raster, dstSRS='EPSG:3083', warpOptions)
else:
    gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_raster, dstSRS='EPSG:3083')
```

or if using unpacking

```py
warpArgs = [output_raster, input_raster, dstSRS='EPSG:3083']

if hasattr(gdal, 'GDALWarpAppOptions'):
    warpOptions = gdal.GDALWarpAppOptions([])
    warpArgs.append(warpOptions)

gdal.Warp(*warpArgs)
```

Not sure testing with condition `hasattr(gdal, 'GDALWarpAppOptions')` is the "best" approach here. So another possibility to manage version differences could be:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

if int(gdal.VersionInfo()) >= 2020000:
    # Do the stuff to manage the difference due to version
    print('version 2.2 and +')
else:
    print('version less than 2.2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all the packages from the environment and reinstalling only the bare minimum (python, gdal and their dependencies) seems to have worked - must have been some dependency / compatibility issue.